# Overloading method throws illegalArgument exception in runtime : Java

Tags: java, overloading, illegalargumentexception

I have a class called basemodel
and there are two classes:

```
Address extends basemodel
E911Addr extends basemodel
```

and in my bean I have two methods

```
public String validate(Address serviceAddress, String action){
}

public String validate(E911Addr e911Address, String action){
}
```

In my ui I have an event action calling this first method
serviceAddress is an object of Address:

```
action=#{bean.validate(serviceAddress,"test")}
```

It is working fine in my testServer but in my local server and the production server it gives

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcept can not convert the object of type
>   class com._8x8.ssp.model.order.Address to class
>   com._8x8.ssp.model.E911Addr

Why is it working in one server and failing in other servers?

Is there anything wrong in this way over overloading?
Appreciate any explanation.

Comment: This seem to be ambigous

Comment: Are the two servers having the same runtimes?

Comment: You don't have the exact same code deployed on both servers.  Rebuild and redeploy everything to fix the problem.

Comment: The way you describe the overloading I see only one potential issue: the first `validate()` method takes an `Address` argument, you have not told us what that is, only `Address1`.

Comment: `com._8x8.ssp.model.order.Address to class com._8x8.ssp.model.E911Addr` In your explanation, I don't see implementation of `com._8x8.ssp.model.order.Address`, there is one as `Address1`. Check If `Address1` & `Address` are referring to different implementation

Comment: thats my typo both are Address.

Comment: In the beginning I also suspected the build, but the md5sum of both the wars are same.

Comment: It’s beginning to sound weird. To answer your question, I believe there is nothing wrong with the overloading. You may want to try renaming one of the `validate` methods to avoid the overlaoding and see what error you get then, it may teach you something about your problem.